Why am I having problems with an external SSD?
I'm using an internal 2280 SATA drive in an enclosure as an external SSD. When I connect it to the computer (Windows 11), the volume is mounted and recognized and even is still usable for a couple of minutes. But then when I try to perform any read-write operations after 2-3 minutes pass (accessing/copying/creating etc), there are 4 things that start to happen:

Explorer freezes and I have to force restart it through the Task Manager.
Explorer doesn't freeze but I get a "Fatal hardware error 0x800701e3" whenever I try to open a nested folder or access a file. When this happens 100% disk usage is shown in the Performance tab in Task Manager.
The disk stops being recognized, loses its name and becomes unaccessible.
Windows freezes and I have to reboot.

Whenever I try to repair the filesystem or check for errors, the utility freezes. The chkdsk command either says that the disk's format is RAW (while Explorer says it's NTFS, and it is still accessible), or runs up to stage 3 and then exits with an error.
The disk has been in use for about 3 months, so it's not old. It's capacity is 2 TB and only 600 GB are currently in use. If I try to create a new partition and format it, either the Disk Management utility freezes (and I have to kill the process), it returns a "Fatal hardware error", or freezes during formatting.
I've already managed to get all the most necessary files from the disk (documents, personal data etc) but there's still content on the disk, which, well, I could sacrifice if required.
Is there any way to fix this or is the disk on the verge of death?

Update: Found some spare storage to relocate the files of second importance. The copying speed returned to normal. The error apparently only occurs if I go too deep into the nested folders. I'll try formatting the entire drive and then post an answer here if it solves the problem.

If trying a different USB lead doesn't fix it, could you test the enclosure with a different disk, or the disk with a different enclosure?

@AndrewMorton, tried 3 different USB leads: 2 of them were USB-C, and one USB-C to USB-A – the same results. Unfortunately, I don't have an extra enclosure to see if it's the thing that's failing.

A slight possibility is that the drive is getting too hot - did the enclosure have a thermal transfer pad that needed the protective plastic to be peeled off? Although those drives can run too hot to be touched comfortably in normal operation.

@AndrewMorton, I have a cheap enclosure, so it only has only one tiny thermal pad – it's on the inner side of the removable panel (the one that you unscrew to intall the 2280). Also, I just checked the drive's temperature through AIDA, and it says that it's 45 degrees Celcius, which is 2 degrees higher than my internal SSD.

45 °C is no problem. Have you tried taking the drive out and putting it back, in case it isn't making a good-enough electrical connection? And I guess you haven't got a vacant socket in the PC that you could try the drive in, or have you?

@AndrewMorton, I do have a vacant socket but it only supports NVMe drives (it isn't electrically wired to have backwards compatibility with regular SATA M.2 2280 disks, I guess). Actually, I justed formatted the drive, disabled defragmentation and indexing, and now it's working as it used to.

I'm glad to hear you now have a working drive :) Note that you should let Windows optimise the drive on a schedule: Windows will see it as an SSD and send a TRIM command instead of defragmenting it. The TRIM command gives the drive's firmware a chance to tidy things up to maintain performance.

@AndrewMorton, I see. Thank you!

Ended up what helped me was to temporarily relocate the disk's contents elsewhere, and then reformat it as Windows prompted me. According to the report from CrystalDiskInfo, the disk itself is healthy (99%), but when I checked it with Defraggler it showed that it was 69% fragmented.
I think that it was the result of the filesystem corruption. As to why it got corrupt in the first place, I think it's because I forcefully disconnected the drive while Adobe After Effects was flushing disk cache, because After Effects froze midway. Most of the fragmented chunks were actually After Effect's and Blender's disk cache files.
